# What is the danger in returning the primitive types?

Tags: javascript, types, constructor

Per [@TobyHo](http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/)

> `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, are all primitive types. If you return one of these types of values from a constructor, it would be ignored and the constructor would go back to its normal behavior of returning the this object.

- What is the danger in returning the primitive types (because of which the constructor returns to it's normal behaviour)?

Comment: There is no "danger". The language spec says that a constructor returns its implicit `this` unless it explicitly returns an object. Primitive types are not objects. Therefore, a constructor returns its implicit `this` if it returns a primitive type.

Comment: It's not a danger. The author is just stating a fact about what happens. It's useful to be aware of that.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi When you call a return to a primitive value, it will be discarded. See my answer please. I cite an example in which this case occurs

Comment: @Vanya, yup, that's what I was saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, technically, any function can be used as a constructor.

But to highlight the function, conceived as constructor, they are called with a capital letter: Animal, rather than animal.

As a rule, the constructor not return anythingюTheir mission - to write down everything you need, in this, that will automatically result

But if an explicit call to return is still there, then it applies a simple rule:

- When the return call to the object,it will be returned instead of
  this.
- When you call a return to a primitive value, it will be discarded.

For example, the object Returns:

```
function BigAnimal() {

    this.name = "Mouse";

    return { name: "Godzilla " };  // <-- return the object
}

alert( new BigAnimal().name );  // Godzilla, we got an object instead of this
```

Here is an example of a line return:

```
function BigAnimal() {

    this.name = "Mouse";

    return "Godzilla"; // <-- return the primitive
}

alert( new BigAnimal().name ); // Mouse, received this (but Godzilla is gone)
```

This feature of the work is registered in the new standard, but it is used very rarely.